# Addressing British nobility in third person

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say "Their Lordship"while referring to British nobility ?

Comment: Why would one use a gender-neutral possessive determiner with a gender-specific title?

Comment: We generally don't address _anyone_ in the third person in English, nobility or not. Why would you want/need to do that? Addressing someone is what the second person is for, and if you're talking to a Lord, you could call him _Your Lordship_, or _My Lord_.

Comment: In fact it should have been referring to British Nobility instead of addressing Nobility.

Comment: There is a very good [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forms_of_address_in_the_United_Kingdom#Eldest_sons.2C_grandsons_and_great-grandsons_of_dukes.2C_marquesses_and_earls) on forms of address in the United Kingdom.

Answer (score 6):

If *referring* to  one noble lord (not *addressing* him) you'd say "His Lordship". For more than one, it would be "Their Lordships".

**A touch of tension among their lordships** - *[BBC NEWS](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-18506621)*

Comment: Your answer really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the thing to be noted here is that the OP seems to be from India.

In Indian culture, it is customary (mandatory) to address a superior (not to speak of nobility, let alone the British -- the rulers at one time) invariably in the plural.

Many such Indianisms can be found in Indian English. It's a geographical  variant, not standard English.

HTH.

---

The edit has changed the context/nature of the question. The question is not clear now. Referring to someone, anyone, you would of course, use the third person, wouldn't you? Is the Q then about the plural?

Comment: The question encompasses both singular and plural. Is it odd to use Their Lordship or Their Lordships depending upon the number of Noble man / Noble men

Comment: In the US, one would say or write "Lord Smith" or even "Ian Smith", not "His Lordship".  I'm not sure what one would say or write if referring to several titled people, where it was important to include the information that they were titled.  I'm pretty sure one would not say "Their Lordships", any more than one would refer to the (previously identified) Princesses (i.e.,Beatrice and Eugenie) as "Their Royal Highnesses".

Answer (score 0):

You can say "his lordship" in the singular and "their lordships" in the plural. "Their lordship" is wrong in any case.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?